# Script - Have I formatted multiple values correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I use the following script, it deletes a information from our database.

I have a few hundred users to delete. I wanted to include them in one script and delete them all. The thing I can't remember is if I can comma delineate them to include them in a single query or not

So if I have the following 3 users, would the script below work correctly to delete all 3 of them?

Comment: No, you should use `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` clause:

```
delete from FILE_Users where USER_ID in ('USER/Jo.Ann', 'USER/Mike.Jordan', 'USER/Jim.Buss')
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use IN to do multiple deletes

```
delete from FILE_Users where USER_ID IN ('USER/Jo.Ann','USER/Mike.Jordan', 'USER/Jim.Buss')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` clause

```
delete from FILE_Users 
where USER_ID in ( 'USER/Jim.Buss', 'USER/Jo.Ann', 'USER/Mike.Jordan');
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause will allow upto 1024 values. If you have more than that then you have multiple options.
One among them is split the comma separated string and use these as table using the connect by query.
This might make the query slower though. 
Or Put this string as external table and using regular expression count and split the values at each comma and delete.
Good luck